# How do I create a sparse matrix for my own class?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have created my own MyInterval class, which allows you to work with interval objects.
To work with vectors, I wrapped it in an additional Array Intervals class.

In the example, I give the most simplified view of these classes:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

class MyInterval:
    
    def __init__(self, inf, sup):
        self.inf = inf
        self.sup = sup
        
class ArrayIntervals:
    
    def __init__(self, intervals):
        self.data = intervals
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.data.__iter__()
```

Sparse matrices can often occur in my tasks and I want to use the scipy library to create sparse matrices.
However, an incorrectly sized matrix is created for the ArrayIntervals class
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'

```py
intervals = ArrayIntervals(np.array([MyInterval(a, b) for a, b in zip([0,2,3], [0,5,6])], dtype=object))
sp.sparse.coo_matrix(intervals)
#<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
#with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Please help me understand why this is happening and what magic method needs to be added to give the answer as below?

```py
intervals = np.array([MyInterval(a, b) if a != b else a for a, b in zip([0,2,3], [0,5,6])], dtype=object)
sp.sparse.coo_matrix(intervals)
#<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
#with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I thought adding the `__iter__` method would help, but it didn't have the desired effect.

Comment: `coo_matrix` called like that expects a 2d numeric numpy array..  I suspect it's calling `np.asarray(intervals)` in an attempt to make such array.

Comment: yes, checking the source it does `M = np.atleast_2d(np.asarray(arg1))` if the input isn't already a sparse matrix or a tuple..

Comment: Hmm, I understand. Thank you.
Please tell me, what should I do to create a sparse array for the ArrayInterval class?

Comment: I don't know what your matrix should look like.  Have you tried the `(data, (row, col))` type  of input?  That's close to what matrix will store.

Comment: 1) Can you add the intended output of what the matrix should contain? 2) Putting MyInterval as the data element of the sparse matrix will take a lot of space, and inhibit vectorization. I estimate that each MyInterval in your matrix will take ~96 bytes, whereas if you re-organized it to store two SciPy sparse arrays for inf and sup, it would take ~24 bytes per MyInterval. Are you storing a large number of these?